# Multiple callouts to Triggered Send not executing in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

Requirement: Users from a website will share products to their friends. On this event i want to send two emails to user(for letting him know what he has shared) and his family members(for letting them know that they have been shared some products)

Approach: I have created two triggered sends in Marketing Cloud and triggering them using REST api call from Apex Trigger using the Future method.

Problem: On every API request i am getting the success response from Marketing Cloud but only the first case is getting queued in the triggered sends.
If the user has provided the emailid's of two family members separated by comma (abc@abc.com, xyz@xyz.com) then i am making two callout. Third would be for the user itself for sharing the products. In this case only one request is getting queued, while all three requests get success response as queued from marketing cloud.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing an async call and getting the ok response, can you do a sync call to see what additional errors may be present

Comment: @EazyE You guessed it right. When changed to SYNC, i got an error as ""Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers."

Comment: @EazyE Can you please explain why this is happening. when i reverse the parameters, the one which is failing gets passed and the other one fails. So basically, whatever follows the first callout, fails.

Comment: You would need to post your calls

Comment: I just got the answer. It is because i am passing the same subscriber id(Lead ID) in all the calls with different emails.

Comment: Thank you for your response! @EazyE

Comment: posted my comments as an answer which you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing a SYNC call vs an ASNYC call to see any errors that are occurring. In this case it appears you are passing the same Subscriberkey for different emailaddress which the system errors on. You would need to pass a unique subkey for each emailaddress